# render model to json and use encode64 on one of the model's columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I am trying to send a model as json. The model has binary data in one of it's columns. For another model I have used

```
format.json {self.encode64(@resource_type.data).to_json}
```

with success, but in that case I only wanted the data column, and not the title etc. What can I do when I want contents from several columns, where only one column's content should be encoded with encode64?

In the following code, I don't know where to put the self.encode64 method.

```
format.json { render :json => @resource.to_json(:only => [:id, :title, :data])}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here.

You could add a `data_base64` method to your model that returned the `data` in base-64 format and then use the `:methods` option to `to_json` in your controller:

```
@resource.to_json(:only => [ :id, :title ], :methods => :data_base64)
```

That would give you a `data_base64` key in the JSON instead of `data` but that might not be a problem.

You could also use `as_json` to get a hash and fix the encoding in the controller:

```
json = @resource.as_json(:only => [ :id, :title, :data ])
json['resource']['data'] = self.encode64(json['resource']['data'])
render :json => json
```

Comment: Thank's. Will look into that tomorrow!

Comment: Couldn't wait till tomorrow. :-) I tried the second alternative. The json['data'] is empty (I tried "puts json['data']") even if "puts json" returns all data.

Comment: @JohanHovda: Sorry, I was missing a level in the `json` hash, should be using `json['resource']['data']` rather than `json['data']` assuming that the `@resource` is a `Resource`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as_json` in model to override this behaviour like this

```
def as_json(options={})
  { :name_of_resource => { :created_at => created_at, binary => encode64(self.data) } }
end
```

You need to specify how he should serialize whole model into json.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank's! I'll try it out tomorrow (it's late here in Norway). :-)